# When using XmlWriter in C#, is there a way to have some elements written on the same line and others on their own respective lines?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlwriter

I'm using XmlWriter to make an xml file, and have an issue as I need some comments to be on the same line as other elements i.e.

`<string> text </string> <!-- comment -->`

However, I also need to have some which are on their own line i.e.

`<string> text </string>`

`<!-- comment -->`

I suspect I can't do this as the setting for indenting the lines has been set at the creation of the writer, but was wondering if anyone might have an idea.

Comment: I can't see it being done with any xml methods. If you use ident == false, then you can take the xml string and add returns where you do not have a comment.  but then you loose other indentations.

Comment: you may need http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/XML-LINQ/AddacommenttoXDocument.htm

Answer (score 0):

If the `Indent` setting is set to false, then it's easy to add your own line breaks using

```
writer.WriteRaw(Environment.NewLine);
```

If the `Indent` setting is set to true, then the writer is inserting line breaks for you and you can't override them on a case-by-case basis.